# Unable to import one js file in another file in react

Tags: reactjs

Unable to import one js file in another file in react
this is what i tried:

(App.js file:)

```js
import React, { Components } from 'react';

import todoinput from './components/todoinput';

import todolist from './components/todolist';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import uuid from "uuid";

function App() {

    return (

    <div><h1>hello</h1><div>

        <todoinput />

  );

}

export default App;
```

(todoinput.js file):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class todoinput extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            
             <div><h1>from todoinput</h1></div>
        );
    }
}
```

when I run this the content from todoinput.js is not displayed please help me.

Comment: are you using any route or switch case to render components as these are two components so app is the root component and if you do not navigate to todoinput then it will not show anything. does it make sense?

Comment: please format this better.

Comment: I made edits please approve it so others can read your question better.

Comment: please ask your question in a proper format So It'll better to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In react renders all your components must be encapsulated in one such as a div.

Example:

```js
function App() {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello</h1>
            // todoinput must be in the same div as all the other sub components
            <todoinput />
        </div>
    );

}
```